# Best way to access files? Database paths vs system "ls"

Tags: database, django, file, static, ls

I'm working in a Django project that stores and serves some static files that users upload.

Actually, we intend to develop a kind of "navigator" to navigate across the folders and files of the user. In the beginning, we started using a "Content" model with a FileField, but given that the folders and files uploaded by users are in actual folders in the hard drive very well located, we are thinking about removing the Content model and just upload files (and create folders) and recreate or navigation system with just calling os.listdir()

So, what do you think is better? Calling os.listdir() whenever necessary or create our navigation windows by fetching the paths from the database?

Comment: I would vote to use paths in the database. If you ever want to extend functionality related to the files, like user permissions or searching via metadata, you will be able to create foreign key relationships. With just a system directory listing these things would become quite un-Djangoic. Just my 2¢